# Lesser load for my app

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I don't know where to properly asked this question in the Stackexchange site. So I will ask it here. Let me know if this question is off topic and I will move it to what Stackexchange site it should properly be.

I have an application (**VB.NET**), that is almost complete, and I want to know what should I be doing to properly optimize the use of it.

Its called *CCTV Mapping System (CMS)*. 
[image][image]
Technically a map, with markers (*or cameras I would say*), also there with the mainForm is what I call, settings panel. A lot of controls are in there, a tabcontrol (3tabs), in which each has labels, textboxes, buttons and a datagridview. This is merely a future project but I want to finalize these sort of things before I make another form for the same concept, *mapping cctv's per floors inside the building*.

Anyway, I want to know which of these are a better option for user input/control in my app in terms of:

1. Load
2. Faster response
3. User experience
4. Proper thing to do

**OPTIONS:**

5. Create a form where it will contain **all** layouts and commands of adding/removing of data + datagridview in *GENERAL FORM* so that, I will only call `generalSettingsForm.Show` to perform these tasks. Then disable unnecessary controls depending on what process had been carried out. (For example, if DVRcommand is click, only DVR controls will be enabled)
6. Create individual forms for each data table that there is.
7. Create a form that contains a number of panel that contain one data table each and show only the panel from what command has been carried out. (For example, DVR, show only `DVRPanel`)
8. Leave it be.

Comment: This is about improving your code/way of work, so I guess this should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: ok thanks, but what's your ideal option before I move this?

Comment: This is such a general question that it's hard to say. You should try using the software yourself, best would be a real world application. Then, whenever you run into something that bothers you: fix it. Be it speed, usability or the like. As a third party that has no knowledge of the application you can't really tell someone how to improve a software. We can help with code not working, but once it left this stage we can't really help you easily.